# How to make a cube root calculator in dashcode

Tags: root, cube, dashcode

Can someone post the javascript to cube root in dashcode

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Dashcode is, but assuming it uses standard JavaScript, just turn it into a power calculation (like you learned at school) and use `Math.pow`:

```
> Math.pow(27, 1/3)
  9
```

The nth root of x is x^(1/n).